# ffmpeg/x265: fixed-GOP, IDR only keyframes, repeating headers

Tags: ffmpeg, h265, hevc

I need to transcode a video to another one with the following properties:

- GOP size is always fixed at a given value
- Only IDR frames are used as key-frames (not I-slices)
- SPS/PPS/VPS frames are repeated every time before the IDR frame.

Is there a way to do this with ffmpeg?

Also, it would be great if you can also tell me of a simple way of verifying all this (perhaps using ffprobe?).

Comment: Which output format?

Comment: H.265 output format.

Comment: As in,  a raw bitstream?

Comment: Frankly, doesn't really matter. I can fix the container if I need to, later. But the raw stream is what matters to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimal command line, for a GOP size of 2 seconds:

`ffmpeg -i input -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) -c:v libx265 -x265-params open-gop=0:scenecut=0:repeat-headers=1 output.hevc`

Verification:

```
ffmpeg -i output.hevc -c copy -bsf:v trace_headers -f null -
```

After each line containing key frame e.g.,

```
Packet: 18115 bytes, key frame, no pts, dts 2319977, duration 40000.
```

You should see the VPS/SPS/PPS. The first `Slice Segment Header` that follows should have a NAL unit type of `20` which is IDR_N_LP.

ffprobe can't invoke bitstream filters.

Comment: The seems to be working. Thanks. The verification command doesn't work for me though ("Unknown bitstream filter trace_headers"). Also, not that it's a problem, but there is a "supplemental enhancement information" NAL after VPS, SPS and PPS which wasn't there before. Could you tell me why this particular command causes that to appear?

Comment: Oh, and also, the `expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)` part of the first ffmpeg command needs to be quoted. I'd suggested you edit that in the interest of the future copy-pasters!

Comment: So maybe I was wrong. I tried this with another video and looks like it does _not_ always work. Keyframes frequently happen before the 250 frames (10 seconds) that I set is up (I'm assuming the `n_forced*2` determines GOP size and I changed it to `n_forced*10`). I tried adding `min-keyint=250:keyint=250` to the x2675 params. No effect. I also tried the `-g` option of ffmpeg. Still the same thing happens.

Comment: if your source is a container with VFR stream and/or fps < 25, then there may not be 250 frames in a 10 second interval. You can change t to n and the value to a frame distance

Comment: The FPS I'm sure is 25 (or so ffprobe says). I'm not sure about VFR (that's variable frame rate, right?), but I think it's unlikely. I think the problem is that whatever we do libx265 seems to not honor min-keyint. Your force_key_frames option _does_ work and it fixes my main issue, but x265 right at the beginning says that `Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 126 / 250 / 0` even though I've set both `min-keyint` and `keyint` to 250.

Comment: If scenecut is 0 then x265 may insert non-IDR I-slices - those aren't keyframes.